# Yet another Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, mpi

I am stuck with this error:

```
mpif90 -o /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build/ed_2.1-opt edmain.o -L/opt/local/lib/libgcc/ -lstdc++ -I/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/include -I/opt/local/include   /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build/ed_2.1-opt.a -lm -lz -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_calchydrosubsurface_", referenced from:
      _ed_model_ in ed_2.1-opt.a(ed_model.o)
...
other similar errors
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build/ed_2.1-opt] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` or including the libraries lstdc++ or lstc++.6 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020140/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-mavericks) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34692/mathlink-linking-error-after-os-x-10-9-mavericks-upgrade) and I had already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474173/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-in-clang) about the same error but still not able to fix it.
The compilation with mpif is needed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `calchydrosubsurface` doesn't sound like a standard library function at all. The problem could be the *order* you add your special libraries. The one using the function ought to be searched before the one implementing it.

Comment: I am sorry, can you be more specific please. By the way the makefile includes a dependency.mk file where all the dependencies are listed and the package compiles fine on other platforms, for this reason I was thinking that the error might depend on the `stdlib` that my mac (10.9) is using.

Comment: The name `_calchydrosubsurface_` that is missing let suggest that the corresponding function is to be found in some Fortran sources of yours (the tailing _ let suggest it is Fortran object). What does a `grep -ri calchydrosubsurface /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/` give?

Comment: `Binary file /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED//build/bin/ed_model.o matches
Binary file /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED//build/bin/lsm_hyd.o matches
Binary file /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED//build/ed_2.1-opt.a matches`
and indeed the f90 file containing the function has been compiled and has produced the corresponding .o file

Comment: Try something like this: `mpif90 -o /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build/ed_2.1-opt edmain.o -Wl,--whole-archive /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build/ed_2.1-opt.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran -L/opt/local/lib/libgcc/ -lstdc++ -lz -lm`

Comment: I had to use -all_load option, OSX equivalent to --whole-archive (?). But the  errors are still there.

Comment: Compiled disabling mpi (using gfortran and gcc) but same errors. No clues?